# Calculate an integral with limit another integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have a list of integrals to do with a structure similar to this one, but I don't know how to attack anyone of them. I hope you can help me doing this one to understand how to do the other ones.

> Calculate the integral of the function
>   $$ 
> F(x)=\int^{\int^x_a\frac{1}{1+\sin^2t}dt}_a\frac{1}{1+\sin^2t}dt
> $$

Another of my questions about this kind of integrals is if doing the first integral doesn't affect the integral of the upper bound even if is over the same variable, and if I can do any of them first since it's the same for both integrals.

Comment: You can just solve it and do both integrations, with the advantage that they are equal, so both are done since you solve the first one. The best way to solve that is substitute u=cos t, since the function is odd on the sin t

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F(1%2Bsin(x)%5E2),x%5D

Comment: @tired My question is not only "solve the integral".

Comment: @Jaime_mc2 thanks. So I can do the first or the second one and it doesn't affect the final result?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois It does not affect since you are calculating a function of x, and you get that x on the last integration

Comment: If $J(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\; dt$, your $F(x) = J(J(x))$.

Comment: @OP what else should u do? the integrals are totally independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\int{\frac{1}{1+{{\sin }^{2}}t\,}}\,dt=\int{\frac{1+{{\tan }^{2}}t}{1+2{{\tan }^{2}}t\,}}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}{{\tan }^{-1}}(\sqrt{2}\tan x)+c$$